# Cant copy from requester pays bucket to my own bucket using the s3 module of aws cli, while I can copy to my machine fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
aws s3 cp s3://arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_0001_001.tar s3://bucket --request-payer requester
```

fails with

> fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

But if I do

```
aws s3 cp s3://arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_0001_001.tar . --request-payer requester
```

it works fine

Additionally this also works, but it only copies one file at a time:

```
aws s3api copy-object --copy-source arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_0001_001.tar --request-payer requester --key arXiv_pdf_0001_001.tar --bucket arxivmanifest
```

Whats going on?

Comment: You say that `aws s3api copy-object` "only copies one file at a time", but that is the case for `aws s3 cp` too.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran the first command, it gave the error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied

This is because the `aws s3 cp` command does *more* than just copy the file by also attempting to copy tagging (it seems). It would also seem that the bucket has not granted permissions for the `GetObjectTagging` API call.

In contrast, the `aws s3api copy-object` command issues a single API call. In fact, all `s3api` commands map to a specific API call. The `aws s3` commands are 'higher level' commands that do more, such as enabling a `--recursive` copy).

Comment: thanks a lot. is there any way to sidestep this in s3 cp?

Comment: There is no mention of tagging in the documentation, so probably not. If you just want to copy that single file, you can use `aws s3api copy-object`. Is your goal is to **copy multiple files**? Do you know the name of the files? What is your _actual_ goal that you are wanting to achieve?

Comment: To copy all files in a bucket. I already wrote a script in python tho, thanks for the help.

Comment: That's interesting... I was unable to list the contents of that bucket. But if it's working for you, that's great!